# How to pass values from product to cart page in shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

in my product page i have this input field for quantity:

```
<input min={{variant.title}} max="240"type="number" id="qty" name="qty" value={{variant.title}} />
```

the value of variant.title is 12, it represents the minimum amount that you could order

my concern is that when i click add to cart button, how do i pass the quantity input value to the quantity input field in cart page?

im pretty sure that the block of code below is the looping for the cart values, but where is the cart object assembled?

```
      {% for item in cart.items %}
      {% include 'cart-item' with item %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here on the Shopify wiki: [Adding a quantity box to your product pages](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/product-page/i-want-to-add-a-quantity-box-to-my-product-pages-so-that-my-clients-can-add-several-items-at-once-to-their-cart-how-do-i-do-this)

If you adjust your input field to have `name="quantity"` the value will be passed to the cart.

For example:

```
<input min="{{variant.title}}" max="240" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="{{variant.title}}" />
```